# Creating edge and vertex identifiers for Python AddIn?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-addin, vertices

[image]

I can create multiple points using the add-in that I created. But the problem is, I don't know how to add edge and vertex identifiers to my tool (like in the picture).

Here is my code :

```py
class ToolClass2(object):
"""Implementation for PPPpoint_addin.tool (Tool)"""
def __init__(self):
    self.enabled = True
    self.shape = "NONE" # Can set to "Line", "Circle" or "Rectangle" for interactive shape drawing and to activate the onLine/Polygon/Circle event sinks.
def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):        
    fc = r"C:\Test\pourpoint.shp"

    pt = arcpy.Point()
    pt.X = float(x)
    pt.Y = float(y)

    ptGeoms = [arcpy.PointGeometry(pt)]
    cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ['SHAPE@'])
    cursor.insertRow([pt])
    del cursor
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what the criteria is for adding edge and vertex points (when, where, why....)?

Comment: my point tool works like adding point tool of arcmap. But doesn't show edges and vertexes of other polygon and line type feature classes. I have to intersect my points with other polygons and lines. And i want to always use this identifiers while i create points. Because my all points have to intersect with other layers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this functionality isn't possible with `pythonaddins`. If you want to make the point you click align with edges or vertices, you will need to create the point after click, add the point to a feature class, and then use the `snap` tool on the feature class.

Comment: Thank you Emil. You are my personal Jesus Christ. Snap method was what i was also thinking, if i fail finding a solution for edge identifiers. I guess i have to go with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the functionality displaying "Edge" or "Vertex" is not possible with `pythonaddins`. The closest you can come is to create a point from the `x` and `y` coordinates and then making use of the Snap tool to achieve the same end result.

Here is a basic script:

```
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference (...spatial reference info...) #spatial reference object
moveLyr = "SnapToMeLayer" #layer to be snapped to edge or vertex

class AlignEdge (object):
    def onMouseUpMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        point = arcpy.Point (x, y)
        clickGeom = arcpy.Geometry ("POINT", point, sr)
        arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management ("in_memory", "pnt", "POINT",
                                             spatial_reference = sr)
        tempPntFc = r"in_memory\pnt"
        with arcpy.da.InsertCursor (tempPntFc, "SHAPE@") as curs:
            curs.insertRow ((clickGeom,))
        #snap 6 feet distance used to allow wiggle room with click
        arcpy.Snap_edit (tempPntFc, [[moveLyr, "EDGE", "6 FEET"]])
        #snapped x and y
        snapX, snapY = arcpy.da.SearchCursor (tempPntFc, "SHAPE@XY").next ()[0]
```